# Python multiple lists loop continue after exception only with one of the lists

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I have the following problem:
I want to loop through 2 lists of unequal length. And I am using try-except. Is there a way to continue the loop for one of the variables after exception while the unaffected variable will is held.

```
try:
 for url,proxy in ([proxy1, proxy2,..],[url1, url2,..])
  call url by proxy
  
 
except #if proxy does not respond an exception is thrown by selenium:
 continue loop with proxy[1] and url[0]
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: List(i) - list of proxies; List(j) - List of Urls. I want to call every url by different proxy and incase that one proxy doesn't work, go to the next while using the same url.

Comment: Show the example with two lists and expected result.

Comment: @MykolaZotko I dont have any, I am thinking how to solve before. I put it in pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save values for the next iteration. For example:

```
import itertools

lst1 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
lst2 = [2, 0, 2]

for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(lst1, lst2):
    try:
        print(i / j)
        # Save the value
        j_ = j
    except:
        print(i / j_)
```

Output:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
```

Comment: Ok thanks that can solve the problem (with writing all the do things code into the except part and using the new variable)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) like so:

```
import itertools

for f, g in itertools.zip_longest(i, j):
    do_things(f, g)
```

In `do_things`, you can handle a case where `f` or `g` is `None`.

If you want to process the lists always with the last element from the shorter list, just pass it to the `zip_longest`:

```
fill = i[-1] if len(i) < len(j) else j[-1]
for f, g in itertools.zip_longest(i, j, fillvalue=fill):
    do_things(f, g)
```

Comment: Thanks! My question is how to handle the exception that way, so the loop continue for f but not for g, so that iteration is still in parallel. So the best case is if f doesn't cause an exception and the logo goes to f+1, g+1. But in case of an exception, caused by a function  with f, the loop goes to f+1, g